# RavenDB index with sorting not sorting

Tags: ravendb

I have the following index created for RavenDB.

```
public class DayOfMonths_AllDaysSortedByOrder : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DayOfMonth, DayOfMonth>
    {
        public DayOfMonths_AllDaysSortedByOrder()
        {
            Map = days => from day in days select new { day };

            Sort(x => x.Order, Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.SortOptions.Int);
        }
    }
```

However, when I get the documents for this index, they are not returned in proper sorted order.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is the extra DayOfMonth here unnecessary: AbstractIndexCreationTask<DayOfMonth, DayOfMonth>? I'm implementing an index now, and I just noticed that <T,T> are for TDocument and TReduceResult. Since you don't have a Reduce function, should/could the signature just be AbstractIndexCreationTask<DayOfMonth>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that your Map line should be like this?

```
Map = days => from day in days select new { day.Order };
```

Comment: I don't think so?  I think that would select a list of the Order values from all the documents instead of actually getting the whole document.  Thanks for trying though. =)

Comment: Sure. I'm curious to see the answer. I saw this link and thought maybe that's what you were missing: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/customizing-results-order. Out of curiosity, any reason you can't sort in your code, instead of doing it in the index?

Comment: Actually, I know the answer to that question. You *could* sort in your code, but that's not the point. This index sorting should work...

Comment: Actually, I have discovered that what you proposed was indeed the right answer!  My concept of what the index was supposed to do was incorrect.  It's not for returning data, but for creating an "index" on the data.  Heh... so. anyway, you were right. =)